# How to iterate dictionary object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Can you please guide, how I iterate dictionary in python.

How I get it one by one like `key: value
                          key: value`
My Code:

```
def dist(dict):
    # z = None
    for i in dict:

        print(dict[i])
        z = i+": " + dict[i]
        # print(z)
        # return z

if __name__ == '__main__':
    k = dist({'B_weeks': '40.0 week, 6.0 day, 20.0 hour, 30.0 minute', 'S_weeks': '2.0 week, 3.0 day, 19.0 hour, 59.0 minute'})
    print(k)
```

Recommended output:

```
   'B_weeks': '40.0 week, 6.0 day, 20.0 hour, 30.0 minute'
   'S_weeks': '2.0 week, 3.0 day, 19.0 hour, 59.0 minute'
```

Ho I return this recommended output in one variable from the given function. because i want to use it in another function.

Comment: `for key, value in dict.items()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Comment: instead of ```for i in dict:```

Comment: What do you mean by "return this recommended output in one variable"? Do you want to return a string of the dict content, or an iterator over key, value pairs? Are you aware that you can just call ``str`` on a dict?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I am passing dictionary like ```{'B_weeks': '40.0 week, 6.0 day, 20.0 hour, 30.0 minute', 'S_weeks': '2.0 week, 3.0 day, 19.0 hour, 59.0 minute'}``` And want output of function like  Recommended output , So how can i get it

Comment: If your dictionary is in `data` you can use `print('\n'.join(f'{key}: {value}' for key, value in data.items()))`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a variable, say `output` and now iterate over the key value pairs and concatenate to the string. Then return the string.

```
output = ""
for k, v in dict.items():
    output += "{}: {} ".format(k,v)

return output
```

Comment: Giving o/p like : ``` B_weeks: 40.0 week, 6.0 day, 20.0 hour, 30.0 minuteS_weeks: 2.0 week, 3.0 day, 19.0 hour, 59.0 minute```
but we need o/p like mention in recommended o/p. NOT IN SINGLE LINE

Comment: please see recommended output from my question. need like that. output should not in single line

Comment: This is probably missing a ``"\n"`` instead of a ``" "``. (Guessing from the "recommended output" in the question.)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, where exactly need to use ```"\n"```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.items()`

```
def dist(k):
    items = k.items()
    for key, value in items:
        print('"{}": "{}"'.format(key, value))
    return items


if __name__ == '__main__':
    k = dist({'B_weeks': '40.0 week, 6.0 day, 20.0 hour, 30.0 minute', 'S_weeks': '2.0 week, 3.0 day, 19.0 hour, 59.0 minute'})
    print(k)
```

Comment: yopur code returing ```dict_items([('B_weeks', '40.0 week, 6.0 day, 20.0 hour, 30.0 minute'), ('S_weeks', '2.0 week, 3.0 day, 19.0 hour, 59.0 minute')])``` need output like mentioned in Recommended output:

Answer (score 0):

```
def dict_comprehension(dictionary):
    out=''
    for key,val in dictionary:
        out+="{}:{}".format(key,val)
    return out
```

Comment: its gives output like ```B_weeks:40.0 week, 6.0 day, 20.0 hour, 30.0 minuteS_weeks:2.0 week, 3.0 day, 19.0 hour, 59.0 minute
```

Comment: pls refer Recommended output:

Comment: To get that output, return the value as a list. Let me ask this,Why do you need to call a function for such a simple situation. because you are wasting a lot of memory in calling and creating the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below.

Code example:

```
def dist(dictionary):
    out=''
    for key,val in dictionary.items():
        out+="'{}':'{}'\n".format(key,val)
    return out


if __name__ == '__main__':
    k = dist({'B_weeks': '40.0 week, 6.0 day, 20.0 hour, 30.0 minute', 'S_weeks': '2.0 week, 3.0 day, 19.0 hour, 59.0 minute'})
    print(k)
```

I have a question, why need the single quote in your recommended output?